# Secret Santa problem

Tags: derangements

I saw this problem on my exams and I just literally wrote down the formula for derangements and derived it but I am not sure if it is the case. This was the problem:

**Problem:** Let there be $n$ number of people and each one of them buys a gift and places them in a bag. Then each member chooses a gift out of the bag without seeing what they choose. What is the probability that none of the $n$ people chooses their own gift?

I was just wondering isnt this just a restatement of the derangement problem? Where the derangement formula is given by:

$$!n=n!\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}$$

Comment: You are right, this is the same as a derangement.

Comment: So is the answer exactly that formula?

Comment: Sure.  The the packages people pick up are precisely a permutation of the original list (originally, everyone was paired with their own package).  You want this to be a permutation with no fixed point, hence a derangement.  The number of derangements is $!n$ as you say  so the desired probability is $\frac {!n}{n!}$.   If $n$ is large, this approaches $\frac 1e$.

Comment: Thank you, how about the $(-1)^i$ term of the summation in your expression?

Comment: Which expression are you talking about?  The sum formula for the number of derangements?  What's the problem with it?

Comment: Like I do nut understand if the answer is $!n$ or $!n/n!$

Comment: Never mind I understand thank you !